# Q: Getting Build Error "Invalid Import Path"

Tags: go, beego

I'm stuck on running the BeeGO app using "bee run" it says
[image]

The thing is I've already have setup properly my `GOPATH` to `D:/Web Dev/GO/BeeGO/test-project/`
and also routers path does exist and I've tried to manual build the file but it doesn't generate an .exe file.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro (64-bit)

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your source that causes this? And try removing the whitespace in your GOPATH?

Comment: sure, here's the [code](http://pastebin.com/QTxy0ANa)

yep, also checked the GOPATH there's no whitespace.

The problem is it is pointing to the correct path, but not sure why it's saying `invalid import path`

Answer (score 2):

GO expects the directory structure under $GOPATH in following ways as described in [code organization](https://golang.org/doc/code.html):

```
$GOPATH/src  <--- where your source code goes
       /pkg
       /bin
```

Instead of placing your source files directly under $GOPATH (D:/Web Dev/GO/BeeGO/test-project/ for your case), you want to move your code under `$GOPATH/src`.

```
D:/Web Dev/GO/BeeGO/test-project/src/main.go
D:/Web Dev/GO/BeeGO/test-project/src/quickstart/routers/routers.go
D:/Web Dev/GO/BeeGO/test-project/src/quickstart/controllers/controllers.go
```

import path should be always starting from `$GOPATH/src`.  `routers.go` can be always imported as `import "quickstart/routers"` and `controllers.go` can be imported as `import "quickstart/controllers"`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you import a package.

The import path is relative to `$GOPATH/src`. use:

```
import "quickstart/routers"
```

Comment: thanks, but actually it should be `"../quickstart/routers"`, if I don't append the `../` GO will append the `src` path which is wrong.

Comment: No, *do not* use relative paths. Your code should be in the `$GOPATH/src`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed the bug from the framework,

What I did:

in `main.go` import from
`"D:/Web Dev/GO/BeeGO/test-project/quickstart/routers"`

I changed it to `_"../quickstart/routers"` make sure to include `_` this means to import the library even if it is not used,

Then in the `routers/router.go` I changed the import path
`"D:/Web Dev/GO/BeeGO/test-project/quickstart/controllers"` to `"../controllers"`

It seems **BeeGO** doesn't generate the template properly and caused the build to fail.

Comment: No, *do not* use relative paths. Your code should be in the $GOPATH/src. It's only going going to cause you more problems like this. http://golang.org/doc/code.html

Answer (score 0):

Another possiblity for this error, is when you copy-paste code from the internet, 
and

```
import "quickstart/routers"
```

became

```
import "quickstart/routers "
```

due to bugs in some CMS/Blog systems (notice the space at the end before the closing quote...).